# RadiusNetworks Android iBeacon Library - failed to bind IBeaconService

Tags: android, ibeacon-android

First of all, what I did is similar to the link ([Android iBeacon Library - How to bind IBeaconManager to service in remote process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24171317/android-ibeacon-library-how-to-bind-ibeaconmanager-to-service-in-remote-proces)):

1. Defined my own *MyIBeaconService* that extends **Service** and implements
   **IBeaconConsumer**. It contains a **IBeaconManager** member, and provides corresponding APIs, such as bind/unbind etc. In **onIBeaconServiceConnect()**, it sets **MonitorNotifier** and **RangeNotifier**, starts monitoring and ranging, and broadcasts **Intent** to activities when corresponding notifier's callbacks get invoked.
2. The main activity binds to **MyIBeaconService** and registers the corresponding **BraodcastReceiver** in **onResume()**.
3. Then when the main activity is successfully bound to **MyIBeaconService**, in ServiceConnection::onServiceConnected(), I call **IBeaconManager.bind** to bind **MyIBeaconService** to **IBeaconService**.

However, MyIBeaconService::onIBeaconServiceConnect has never been invoked. Based on the answer in the link above, I posted the generated AndroidManifest.xml files below:
 1. MyIBeaconService's AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="18" android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>    
<application android:allowBackup="true">
    <service android:name="com.xxx.ibeaconlib.MyIBeaconService">
    </service>
    <service android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:isolatedProcess="false" android:label="iBeacon" android:name="com.radiusnetworks.ibeacon.service.IBeaconService">
    </service>
    <service android:enabled="true" android:name="com.radiusnetworks.ibeacon.IBeaconIntentProcessor">
    </service>
</application>
```

2. MyIBeaconService's project.properties

```
target=android-19
android.library=true
manifestmerger.enabled=true
android.library.reference.1=../../../Downloads/AndroidIBeaconLibrary
```

3. My Android Application's AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="18" android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
<application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.radiusnetworks.ibeaconreference.MonitoringActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.radiusnetworks.ibeaconreference.RangingActivity">
        <intent-filter>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.radiusnetworks.ibeaconreference.BackgroundActivity">
        <intent-filter>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name="com.xxx.ibeaconlib.MyIBeaconService">
    </service>
<service android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:isolatedProcess="false" android:label="iBeacon" android:name="com.radiusnetworks.ibeacon.service.IBeaconService">
</service>
<service android:enabled="true" android:name="com.radiusnetworks.ibeacon.IBeaconIntentProcessor">
</service>
</application>
```

4. Android Application's project.properties

```
   target=android-19  
   manifestmerger.enabled=true //please confirm this line is added and remove the comment then
   android.library.reference.1=../../Documents/workspace/iBeaconLib
```

Comment: In your application/project, an important manual edit required in project properties:  
 manifestmerger.enabled , set it as true and check that

Comment: Thanks for reply. I had that configuration in the project.properties. Just forgot to mention that.

Comment: okay so you have both the manifestmerger.enabled=true and
android.library.reference.1=../AndroidIBeaconLibrary configured..right?, can you post the onIBeaconServiceConnect()

Comment: Yes, let me try to update my original post to add those. Thanks for reply.

Comment: I put the breakpoint at onIBeaconServiceConnect(), it did not get invoked. Thanks.

Comment: pls check the question edit... excuse it if you just missed it copy pasting from the project properties

Comment: @user2450263: I have updated my question to have those project. properties. Thanks.

Comment: @user2450263 : I had those configuration you mentioned, please refer to my update for detail. The issue is there even with those configuration presented. Thanks.

Comment: remove the manifest.merger=true in project.properties in step 4 of yours. change your manifest service declarations to the below...  <service
            android:name="com.radiusnetworks.ibeacon.service.IBeaconService"
            android:label="iBeacon" >
        </service>
        <service
            android:name="com.radiusnetworks.ibeacon.IBeaconIntentProcessor"
            android:enabled="true" >
        </service>